# Can you [visual]-ize the flames?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual) could mean a lot of things. Is it too broad to use?

Comment: From tag wiki: Should not been use, use vb.net instead

Comment: *There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet!* Somebody uses it as visualization, somebody uses it as User Interface... simply redirecting to [tag:vb.net] may not be appropriate.

Comment: I copy-edited and moderated a swath of them, now only 50 left.

Comment: It is just clumsy tag entry by the questioner.  Instead of, say, using [visual-c++] they type [visual] [c++].  Then click the Submit button and stare helplessly at the result when the tag reorder to [c++] [foo] [bar] [visual] without any idea whatsoever how to put the back in the right order.  It is a bit of a science :)

Comment: Burn it with fire!

Comment: I can visualize this tag burning...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just finished the last ones. Thanks to those who pitched in.

[image: Trogdor]

Comment: Unfortunately, there was one more just now. So now it'll take longer for the system to clean it up. =/

Comment: @jpmc26: And two more.

Comment: Maybe we should request a black list. @NathanTuggy

Comment: @jpmc26: Only if it keeps going too much longer. Checking back in around 2:30 UTC should help a lot.

Comment: @NathanTuggy keeping it in check should be done more aggressively, since editing several questions at once may be taxing and mistakes can happen. You can keep watch http://stackexchange.com/filters/215389/http-meta-stackoverflow-com-q-312062

Comment: @Braiam Does that filter auto refresh or anything? Otherwise, we could've just used the tag link [tag:visual]... lol.

Comment: @jpmc26 tag pages don't have RSS feed anymore :(

Comment: @jpmc26 [I don't believe filters have live refresh](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142070/add-live-updates-to-stackexchange-com-tag-filters).

Comment: And lo, it is gone.

Comment: [Greetings from 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403536/why-did-the-newest-visual-tag-got-so-many-watchers?cb=1)