# Why did the newest visual tag get so many watchers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-watching

I got to the [newest tags first page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1&tab=new) and looked at the newest tag, [visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual). But when I hovered on it, I got this:

[image: tag tooltip for the "visual" tag showing that it has 1 question and 3.2k watchers]

How this could happen? There is only one question (actually zero, but not updated), and it was created 6 minutes ago.

[image: tag card for the "visual" tag showing that it has 1 question and was created 6 mins ago]

But *how* can it get *3.2k* watchers?

And (from the comments) maybe it was recreated, and then the watchers count should get reset.

Comment: 0 question now. Meta effect? But still 3.2k watchers

Comment: Because it's probably existed for a long time, but has been (previously) missed used for other products; such as taging [tag:visual] for [tag:visual-studio].

Comment: @Larnu It says it was created 6 mins ago when the pic was taken (11 now)

Comment: @TheOtterlord if it was deleted then re-created, then it will have a new creation time.

Comment: People can watch a tag that is then deleted, @TheOtterlord . Most likely they watch it so that they can fix it.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Although I thought it would have lost the subs as it did questions?

Comment: Oh, so it existed, but it was deleted, and re-created, but the previous users(who have watched it) still got watched?

Comment: [Related](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+newly+created+tag+has+lots+of+watchers): [The \[music\] is back with followers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382460/4642212).

Comment: Seems so, but all questions are no longer associated with the tag it apparently?

Comment: Then maybe it has to be get reset?

Comment: @TheOtterlord yes, in order to delete a tag, there should be no questions that use it. The deletion happens automatically if a tag is unused for some time.

Comment: "*Then maybe it has to be reset?*" I'd say that it maybe shouldn't exist instead. It must have been removed for a reason last time around. I'm going to guess because it's vague and useless by itself. Is there something concrete it should be applied to now? For "visual", the answer is probably "no". If there is a product called that, it should probably be tagged `[company-visual]` or similar to distinguish it.

Comment: [Seems `[visual]` was previously burninated 5 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312062/can-you-visual-ize-the-flames) (almost exactly to the day!).

Comment: Oh, then maybe it should get burniated.

Comment: @VLAZ Should I post a new question for the tag should be burniated?

Comment: @ppwater The tag will be automatically deleted soon, as it has 0 questions.

Comment: @user4642212 You assume that the mindless hordes who perpetually find a way to mistag their terrible questions won't manage to use this particular tag? You're funny.

Comment: Can't we just lock it? "Visual" is not a programming concept, until the day someone names their project just "Visual". Oh [wait](https://github.com/danomatika/Visual).

Comment: Oh, :) well, it says This project is dead. See [loaf](https://github.com/danomatika/loaf) instead.

Comment: @IanKemp recently someone mentioned `[c][sharp]` tagged questions and I've seen one recently too, so `[visual][basic]` or `[visual][c][sharp]` would not surprise me

Comment: So perhaps even after a tag is deleted it retains viewership/follower information?

Comment: @jps: Indeed, `[visual][basic]` seems like a very understandable mistake to me; that's what you get if you type 'Visual Basic' into the tags field.

Comment: No point being visual if no one is watching...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lots of comments with answers, but no actual answers. Tsk, tsk.

The [visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual) tag was [burninated (i.e., completely removed from the system)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312062) almost exactly 5 years ago. But there was nothing put in place to prevent the tag from ever being created again, which is apparently what happened here: someone added a [visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual) tag to one of their questions, and boom, the tag was reborn.

When a tag is removed, its list of followers is not cleared, so the reincarnation of the tag brought back all of the followers.

As for why such a stupid tag had so many followers, well, it's probably because during the earlier clean-up and removal of the tag, people were watching it to stay on top of new questions that were added with that tag. Tag burnination is hard enough to do as it is; it's even harder if new questions with that tag get added faster than you can clean up existing ones. Aside from that, there's the fact that people watch tags for *all kinds of reasons*, which I dare not even speculate about.

The [visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual) tag is an orphan now, once again, having no questions to its name. These ["zombie" tags are automatically removed from the system by a script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251221), so soon, you will not even see it in the list of all tags.

Comment: ah, so [tag:status-bydesign] okay. thanks for the nice answer